# Can we update the FAQ to reflect the apparent change in EoL policy?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope, site-faq

*This is a question about editing the FAQ. This is not a good place to discuss whether or not we should allow EoL questions. We already have a meta question (actually, three) for that. (See below.)*

It seems community consensus on the acceptability of questions about EoL releases has shifted over the past ~1 year. Judging by votes on meta:

- [Around November '11](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2122/should-questions-about-using-end-of-life-ubuntu-releases-be-closed), we overwhelmingly supported allowing them.
- [Around May '12](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3229/dealing-with-past-eol-release-questions), we were about evenly split. At most there was perhaps a slight preference for allowing them.
- [Around December '12](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5611/should-we-allow-questions-that-are-about-releases-which-are-considered-end-of-li), we had **a ~2:1 majority in favor of considering new questions about EoL releases off-topic**.

Disclosures:

- This is my reading of the data. Please take a look yourself, in case you disagree with my analysis.
- If people voted on those questions much more recently than they were asked, their votes factor into my accounting. That is, I'm looking at the votes as they are right now. I did not record what they *were* at the time.
- On the underlying issue, I lean slightly toward the position that EoL questions should be allowed here. I don't think that is really a problem here, since **this question is about effectively documenting and enforcing the new policy** (that I slightly disagree with). But maybe some sort of conflict of interest will arise in the future--so now you know.

Now, we appear to be closing questions as off-topic for being about EoL releases.

(Here's [one example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248314/acer-travelmate-2300-enable-wireless-in-ubuntu-11-04), though it might end up reopened since the OP needs a solution in order to upgrade.)

This seems reasonable; if the votes on that meta question represent the community as a whole, then most of us don't want these questions.

So, assuming we're going to continue closing them, **can we edit the FAQ to make the new policy clear?**

Right now it is not; reading the FAQ strongly suggests that EoL questions are welcome.

Please answer this question if you:

- have an opinion about whether or not we should edit the FAQ.
- have other information pertinent to this question that is better as an answer than a comment.
- believe my evaluation of current community opinion is mistaken.
- believe the current majority is insufficient to support a policy of closing these questions.
- believe we should close these questions but, for some reason, should not edit the FAQ.

Please post elsewhere instead (perhaps commenting here--within reason--to provide a link) if you:

- don't have an opinion about whether or not the FAQ should change, but want to discuss the issue of EoL questions further (you can use the existing questions for that).
- think the majority is sufficient to support the policy of closing EoL questions, but oppose it anyway because you feel *it's so important* to keep them open (for that, you should probably post in the existing questions, and if that's not enough, post one new question).

So:

1. Should we edit the FAQ?
2. If not, *why not*?
3. If so, then (optionally) exactly *what should it say?*

Comment: Also, [this wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) shows which releases are still supported and which ones are Eol.

Comment: @Seth Yes, the [modified FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions) has [a link to that](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok.

Comment: I see the FAQ has been updated. Thanks! I'll probably accept this answer soon, but *further discussion and more answers is certainly welcome*.