# Should we go ahead and delete out-dated content?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should questions about using end-of-life Ubuntu releases be closed?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2122/should-questions-about-using-end-of-life-ubuntu-releases-be-closed)

[Boot failure : No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!](https://askubuntu.com/q/30374/10698)

I think this question should be closed because:

- it has no (Ask Ubuntu) owner
- it's over a year old
- about 10.10
- an old boot-failure

either it's **too localized** or **not constructive**.

Comment: It has owner ,but he may not be a askubuntu member,but still his E mail address may stored in stackexchange database

Comment: it has no active owner, and nothing has happened on the question for over a year.

Comment: waiting for the replay from the moderators, 10.10 will stop support after releasing 12.04

Comment: Closed as an exact duplicate because honestly, it is.

Comment: That particular question has over 10,000 views - it's definitely not a too localised problem!

Comment: @jrg my point wasn't that he used 10.10, my point was that a problem with the bootloader on one version of 10.10, that's local...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The decision to close this should be a **community decision**.

I note you are almost at the 3K rep mark and thus will achieve the ability to vote to close.

There is an answer voted +3.  In Ask Ubuntu terms this classifies the question as being "Answered" i.e. it doesnt appear in the unanswered lists.  A question doesnt have to have an "accepted" mark to achieve answered status.

Comment: ok, I get your point. But I still think it's an out-dated question.  but I get why it wont be closed, and shouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

- ### it has no (Ask Ubuntu) owner

  It has an owner, **its called Ask Ubuntu and Stack Exchange** via the copyrights license that Stack Exchange uses. All the work you produce on the site is considered owned by public domain, not user defined.

  Just because the user is not here anymore to reply to anything does not mean it should be deleted. In fact, according to the license *a user cannot go ahead and start deleting his own content just because he thinks that's what should be done*.
- ### it's over a year old

  So everything over a year needs to be removed from the site? Don't label things abandoned just because... It has answers and it contains valid information for anyone still looking for that information.
- ### about 10.10 / an old boot-failure

  That is no reason to delete things on the site. I think you are referring to it as *that release its not supported anymore, so we should delete it*.

  That is just wrong, there might be people still using it even if its not supported anymore, ie: Windows XP mainstream support is long gone, but I still use it professionally and that requires me to look for information to solve issues from time to time. Thank Darwin that the internet doesn't go ahead and deletes random stuff just because ***its outdated and support has ended***.

---

In the end, this should be a community decision. As Fossy-pants says there, you are almost 3k, if you want to vote on this to be closed you should try harder to get the privilege of doing so.

Meta is really not the place to take these things. Unless its urgent, sensible content, offensive in some way that deserves discussion, avoid creating a fuzz where there is not.

Get another 50 reputation, vote to close it, link it in the regulators and see if anyone else agrees with your reasons. That's what needs to be done here.

Comment: ... I'm tempted to downvote this excellent answer - just for one reason only ;)

Comment: There is no love left for me :{P