# Why is it allowed for an older question to be marked as a duplicate of a newer question?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12098/what-does-outputting-to-dev-null-accomplish-in-bash-scripts) is my question, asked way back in 2010 with a lot of upvotes and many useful answers. In late July of this year it was marked as a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350208/what-does-2-dev-null-mean) question, filed in 2013.

Why was this done? Just because the newer question had a few less upvotes? Why does the duplicates system even allow this?

Comment: The newer question has an answer that's a little more detailed and is also more upvoted. This is one of the main reasons you can dupe to a newer question (the other being outdated info).

Comment: Related discussion at meta.stackexchange: [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha)

Answer (score 18):

It has less to do with the *age* of the posts and more with the *quality*.

As you can see, the [newer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350208/what-does-2-dev-null-mean) question has a couple of high quality answers, which go into a decent amount of detail around `>`, `1>`, `1>` and `&>` and what they each do and why you might want to use one over the other.

The [older](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12098/what-does-outputting-to-dev-null-accomplish-in-bash-scripts) question doesn't have as high quality of answers, so it was marked and closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Views are also an important consideration.  The newer question has over twice the views of the first.  Duplicates are only a matter of organizing information. Not a punishment.  The choice of how to set them up ultimately comes down to the best organization of the information.

Answer (score 5):

I remember a comment made by David Foerster on one of my posts. The comment stated:

> Duplicates are marked irrespective of the dates posted. Duplicated are considered on the quality of posts.

Answer (score 0):

Stack exchange's purpose is to be a rich, navigable archive of useful information for future users of the internet to refer to.

Stack exchange does not care about your user experience except insofar as it directly helps accomplish the goal described above.

Also, you will notice that they have gotten much stricter about question-asking as time has gone on, so I would say back in 2013 when the second variant was originally asked, they weren't vetting carefully for duplicates.  By the time the reviewers decided to mark it as a duplicate, the second question probably had received much more attention and was determined to be the more useful resource for future Googlers to arrive at.